# How to have first column position fixed on table?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have a table that composed of many columns. In the first column, I want it to be fixed while scrolling to the right.

How can I apply using `position:fixed;` in CSS or Javascript because the first column and second column collides? Hope anyone can help me here.

```css
#table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#th, #td {
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;

}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
```

```html
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table id="table">
    <tr>
      <th id="th">First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="td">Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="td">Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="td">Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Your table structure should be like this

<div>
<table>
        <tr><th class="headingcol">Points</th><td class="spacing">50</td><td class="long">50</td></tr>
        <tr><th class="headingcol">Points</th><td class="spacing">50</td><td class="long">50</td></tr>
        <tr><th class="headingcol">Points</th><td class="spacing">50</td><td class="long">50</td></tr>
        <tr><th class="headingcol">Points</th><td class="spacing">50</td><td class="long">50</td></tr>
        <tr><th class="headingcol">Points</th><td class="spacing">50</td><td class="long">50</td></tr>
        <tr><th class="headingcol">Points</th><td class="spacing">50</td><td class="long">50</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

and css like:

```
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
}

td, th {
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-top-width: 0px;
}

div {
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  margin-left: 5em;
  overflow-y: visible;
  padding: 0;
}

.headingcol{
  position: absolute;
  width: 5em;
  left: 0;
  top: auto;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  /*only relevant for first row*/
  margin-top: -1px;
  /*compensate for top border*/
}

.headingcol:before {
  content: 'Row ';
}

.spacing{
  background: yellow;
  letter-spacing: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty here is a starting point to get you going - what I've done (not sure if you're able to with possible constraints of how the table is generated) is separate your first column into one table and put the rest into a second table. Each table is wrapped inside of a div that controls the display of that individual table.

https://jsfiddle.net/f2zoyd1y/1/

**HTML**

```
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <div id="table1-wrapper">
      <table id="table1">
         <!-- Your first column goes in here -->
      </table>
  </div>
  <div id="table2-wrapper">
      <table id="table2">
         <!-- The rest of it goes in here -->
      </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#table1,
#table 2 { 
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;  
  border: 1px solid #ddd; 
}
#table1-wrapper {
  width:auto;
  float:left;
  position:fixed;
  left:0px;
  z-index:9999;
  background-color:#fff; 
}
#table2-wrapper {
  width:auto;
  float:left;
  margin-left:73px;   /* offsets by the width of the first table */
  background-color:#fff;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

Basically the "wrapper" divs set the widths and float the tables so that they appear side by side. The first table wrapper is set to fixed and has a high z-index so that the second table will scroll underneath it when the window gets to small.

The one small wrinkle here is that as your shrink the viewport your second table "last name" column will line break. At that point you'd need to use a media query to force the "first name" to break as well (or set the wrapper div to a width that will force the line break for you) so that everything looks good still. Given that the rendering section of a JSfiddle isn't the entire viewport i'm unable to guess at what width that would need to be implemented.

Comment: Sir Good pm But row will not be align.

Comment: @Gatzmar could you be more specific, what row won't align? If it's that the second table look longer on a small screen it's because you need to force you first table to link break